# Can I play on the South Asia servers with a North American copy of StarCraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am currently living in the United States, but I might go to South Asia after a couple of months, where the latency with NA servers will not be that great.

Can I play on the South Asia servers if I buy the NA version of the game?
If so, is it possible to switch an account made on the NA servers to the South Asia servers?

Comment: Welcome to Gaming.SE farhan! I edited your question to exclude your question asking where you could buy another version of the game, since such questions are considered off-topic on our site. Please see the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You buy account for specific region and can play just there.

Comment: I have found one exception. The Australian version has access to both NA and Australian server.